# Converting Layout/Bookmark python code to script tool?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool, bookmarks

I have a python script that will position the scale bar, north arrow, title, and legend on a map layout in ArcGIS Pro. This script also references a bookmark and then exports the layout to a PDF. I need to turn this script into a script tool so that it can be used in ModelBuilder, but I have no idea where to start.

Here is the python script I need to convert to a script tool in ArcGIS Pro.

```
# input name of layout

    p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
    lyt = p.listLayouts("Test")[0]

# Reposition the scale bar

    scaleBar = lyt.listElements("MAPSURROUND_ELEMENT", "Scale Bar")[0]
    mf = scaleBar.mapFrame
    scaleBar.elementPositionX = mf.elementPositionX + 0.0
    scaleBar.elementPositionY = mf.elementPositionY - 0.5

# Reposition the north arrow

    northArrow = lyt.listElements("MAPSURROUND_ELEMENT", "North Arrow")[0]
    mf = northArrow.mapFrame
    northArrow.elementPositionX = mf.elementPositionX + 8.8
    northArrow.elementPositionY = mf.elementPositionY + 0.7

# Align the title with the center of the map frame

    title = lyt.listElements("TEXT_ELEMENT","Name of Map Text")[0]
    mf = lyt.listElements('MAPFRAME_ELEMENT',"Map Frame")[0]
    title.elementPositionX = mf.elementPositionX + (mf.elementWidth / 3.7)
    title.elementPositionY = mf.elementPositionY + (mf.elementHeight / 0.98)

# Reposition the Legend and fix legend title

    legend = lyt.listElements("LEGEND_ELEMENT", "Legend")[0]
    legend.title = "Legend"
    legend.elementPositionX = mf.elementPositionX + 7.7
    legend.elementPositionY = mf.elementPositionY + 7.15

# setting layout to bookmark

    aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("Current")

# add name of layout

    lyt = aprx.listLayouts("Test")[0]
    mf = lyt.listElements("MAPFRAME_ELEMENT")[0]

# add name of bookmark and export as PDF

    bkmks = mf.map.listBookmarks("Castro_Py")
    for bkmk in bkmks:
      mf.zoomToBookmark(bkmk)
    lyt.exportToPDF(r"C:\arcGIS_Shared\Exports" + "\\" + bkmk.name + ".pdf")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Create a script tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/basics/create-a-python-script-tool.htm) is the documentation for creating script tools. You need to create a new toolbox, then add your script and configure the parameters as desired.

Note that if you want to reuse this script for other projects, then you need to make the [variables dynamic](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/getparameterastext.htm). use these inputs in the tool parameters pane when creating the tool.

Comment: Thanks for the resources. Just to clarify. If I don't want to reuse the script for future projects, I could just leave it as it is now??? Or do I still need the GetParameterAsText?

Comment: if its for one time use and the file paths are not changing then you dont need to prompt the user for an input